# Could not load file or assembly PDFNET or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to reference the PDFNET dll from PDFTron in one of my website projects. But it is giving me the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'PDFNet' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I am using windows 64bit version and my VS2010 is also set to use ANYCPU build. It works fine when I reference it in a web application project but not a website one. Can't figure out the reason why doesnt it work for website projects. The PDFNET dll is also a x64 bit dll.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I saw the answer here: [Could not load file or assembly 'PDFNet' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498256/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-pdfnet-or-one-of-its-dependencies-an-attempt)

I had my app pool set to enable 32-bit applications.  Changed that True to False, and all was fine.