# Third party dlls not loading in windows docker container

Tags: docker, .net-6.0

I am getting issue "Unable to load DLL ‘PDFNetC’ or one of its dependencies" when running pdftron .net core in windows docker container.
Where should I add the “PDFNetC.dll” in container to make this work. I have added it at all the possible locations but not working

Comment: Have you check 32 bit vs 64 bit version of DLL?

Comment: Go through this. https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/dotnetcore/get-started/integration/windows/#initial-setup

Comment: This might help you as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498256/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-pdfnet-or-one-of-its-dependencies-an-attempt